# Excel SUMIFS comparing to date defined in named value

Tags: excel, date, sumifs

My situation is thus:

I have two tables.  One is a list of invoices, each of which is assigned a project code.  The other is a list of projects assigned a matching code.  I'm trying to sum the total of all invoices before a specific date.  The date itself is defined as a Named Value.  So...

Named value: `Q1_CUTOFF = DATE(2014,4,1)`

Formula on the Project table is:

```
=SUMIFS(Invoices[Cost],B3,Invoices[Code],Invoices[Date],"<=" & Q1_CUTOFF)
```

...where B3 is the project code.  However, this is throwing a #VALUE! error.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: IMHO it belongs to SuperUser instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to correct your formula as follows:

```
=SUMIFS(Invoices[Cost],Invoices[Code],B3,Invoices[Date],"<=" & Q1_CUTOFF)
```

Comment: Ha!  Thanks... you stare at something for too long, you start missing the obvious.